# Android create hidden picture activity using timer ,background save to sd card

Tags: android

I know using intent you can save jpeg from camera to sd card .

I need assistance :

I want to create a Timer that saves appends  a jpeg from the camera at a certain specified interval  to sd card .

I also want to  create a function that  automatically  uploads the jpeg on new append to my webserver..

any assistance will be really appreciated  basic idea is to . capture jpg on intervals and every pic saved to be auto uploaded to webserver.